# What are the effects of changing the default Staging folder path in ArcGIS Server 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1

I want to change Staging folder path in ArcGIS Server 10.1.

The reason is that in my C drive very low space is available and my default staging folder was created at

> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.1\StagingFolder

and I want to change the location on D drive.Going through [web help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000583000000) also. So are there any effects on ArcGIS Server connection settings and Existing map services?

Thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sunil, the Staging folder is used only as a temporary storage place when publishing services (by saving the .sd files there) or when you want to close the Service Editor and preserve the changes made (by saving a .sddraft files there). Existing services are not aware of the Staging folder as long as they have been successfully published on the server.

Personally, when making a new installation of the Server, I change the default Staging folder to somewhere on the root because the ArcGIS Server Account should have sufficient privileges to be able to get the files when the Stage Service and Upload Service Definition GP tools run.

Comment: Thanks dear : ) Perfect explanation . I was able to move successfully the staging folder

Comment: No problem. Just as a comment, when you update the Staging folder in ArcMap, all the current connections to the server will get the new path automatically updated in the Staging Folder parameter of the ArcGIS Server Connection Properties window.