# Deleting contents of Staging folder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, delete

Is it safe to delete the contents of the ArcGIS Desktop Staging folder to free up disk space?

This would be the example file location: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.8\Staging`

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61908/what-are-the-effects-of-changing-the-default-staging-folder-path-in-arcgis-serve